# How to request for select tag name choice, not a value choice in flask?

Tags: python, html, select, flask, html-select

Let's say you have the following form in HTML:

```
<form method="POST">        
    <select class="form-control" id="startyear" name="startyear">
        <option value="2005">first</option>
        <option value="2006">second</option>
        <option value="2007">third</option></select>
</form>
```

I know that in order to access the **value** of select field in flask one needs to request:

```
len = request.form.get(startyear)
```

This way however, we obtain values, so "2005", "2006" etc. Is there a way to obtain names of those values instead? So "first", "second" etc.? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find details here [*select* developer.Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

> Each *option* element should have a value attribute containing the data value to submit to the server when that option is selected; if **no value** attribute is included, the value defaults to **the text** contained inside the element

So get the text : don't set the value, if you set the value you'll get it

Comment: Thank you! It was easier than i thought! I would upvote your comment but I dont have enough reputation

Comment: @kikatuso you can accept the answer (maybe vote up the answer too ?)